# Why this reopen votes review is finished with 2 reopen and 2 leave closed votes?

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

I was reviewing reopen votes queue and got this one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/23841492

I decided to go to the question page to read more carefully both the question and the answers to get the whole idea why it can be reopened. Then I returned to the review page and it says that the review was completed (as you can see, reopened), but the votes count is 2/2. Why is that? Is this a bug?

Comment: There were two reopen votes from the review queue and an additional one from outside the queue. Three reopen votes are enough to get a question reopened.

Comment: There are 3 re-open votes as you can see in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2174927/timeline) and [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2174927/revisions). The 3rd one didn't come from a review so it's not part of the review summary.

Comment: If you check the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2174927/timeline) of the post, there is another vote by *Saturnix* outside of review.

Comment: @ivarni oh wow, thanks for the timeline link, never knew about it. Is there link to it somewhere in the interface or one has to know about it to visit it?

Comment: @YakovL There's no link, but they all follow the same pattern, just replace the post id. There are some userscripts floating around that adds a link though.

Comment: There are userscripts available to add a timeline link under each question: https://stackapps.com/search?q=timeline